# Limit result set size returned to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a set of users that have access to SSMS on Prod. I'm not allowed to revoke their access but every once in a while they will run a query large enough that the temp file takes up all of the free space on C:\ and crashes the server.

I'm looking for a way to limit the result set size returned to any SSMS connection to less than 2gb or some limit like that.

I'm having this problem on all version from 2005 - 2014 so solutions on any or all of those versions will be welcome.

Right now the only thing I have in mind to mitigate this problem is a Nagios alert for large temp results files.

FYI I'm very much aware of how bad this problem is so I would rather not discuss why this situation exists.

Comment: When you right click a query window in SSMS, and choose "Query Options", the first option is to limit the number of rows returned before SQL stops processing your query.   I didn't find anything immediately, but I would imagine the default value for the server is in a .ini file somewhere, or maybe in the registry.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how that option got by me. I'm looking now for the registry key to see if I can set it for all users. I'll use a log in script if I have to!!

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to explore setting up a DW. Then gives these users all the access they want there and keep your production OLTP safe from people who are dangerous. It would solve both issues at once.

Comment: Does it happen on specific stored procedure / table? If the number of affected procedures/tables is not that extensive maybe you can wrap the original procedure in other procedure and execute it with `top x` directive. Something like: `select top 1000 from ( spTheOriginalProcedure )`. The wrapper could be parametrize so you can control when it gets the limited result. But it's rather hacky approach.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski: No I can't count on any specific procedure causing the problem. Users have access to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: @TabAllerman that option is client-side, not server-side. The change would have to be made per-user

Comment: @TDavis, well based on the fact OP says the users keep filling up the C: drive and crashing the server, I assume the users are actually using the server as the client.   Otherwise they'd just be crashing their own boxes instead of the server, and OP could just laugh when they call to complain.

Comment: @Tab Allerman: I took OPs comment to mean that TempDB is on the C drive of the server and their querys are causing autogrowth of TempDB to fill the C drive of the server.

Comment: The TempDB is not what is filling up. It's the volume of data returned to Management Studio that it attempts to store in the same temp directory that it keeps un saved query tabs. That distinction is what makes this problem tough to google. Most assume the problem is tempDB and it's not. It's a temp file generated by SSMS.

Comment: Oh, well thats totally different then. I take it there is one copy of SSMS on the server and people RDP in to use it?

Comment: @TDavis There is one copy but I know SSMS stores at least some settings like font and appearance settings on a per user basis in the registry. I'll have to figure out if there is a global way to set this limit and if I can restrict it from being undone.

Answer (score 1):

Oooh boy. Ok.

Step 1 is to limit the damage users can do through system configuration. Generally, when you set up a SQL Server you want to have 4 different partitions:

- OS
- Paging
- TempDB
- Log
- Data

Doing this not only improves performance, but prevents Autogrowth on Logs or TempDB from taking a dump on your OS partition. You only kill the SQL Server instance when you run out of disk, not the OS itself. As a first step, I would create a new partition for your Temp DB and move it:

[Example of moving temp db](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx#Examples)

As to actually limiting the size of the query they can run, its not so simple. SQL Server does have a Resource Governor that lets you limit the CPU utilization and Disk utilization by user, but not the total amount of data returned in a query.

[Resource Governor on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

Finally, consider looking at what it is they are trying to pull with such massive queries. Maybe they have bad joins causing cartesian results and dont realize it. Consider setting up a few views for them that do the heavy lifting (major table joins and so-forth) so that they no longer need direct table access (**hint-hint-wink-wink**) and you can more appropriately govern what they are doing in the DB since you control the view definitions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't affect the actual design of the system. It must stay standard. I can only affect settings on the engine, or settings in Management Studio.